# EditText and Button side by side

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I want to present in my layout an `EditText` and a `Button` side by side with a small space (margin) between them. I don't want to set a fixed size (I think that's a bad habit).

How to do that?

**My Try:**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:text="Search" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `RelativeLayout`; however, you cannot created a flexible design within that type of `ViewGroup`. You must use a `LinearLayout`.

We use `android:layout_weight="1"` along with the `android:layout_width="0dp"` to create a flexible control. Adjust the weight number for different size ratios.

Afterwards, we use `android:layout_margin` on both controls so the resulting weighted size of each is equal.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linear layout with horizontal orientation and add an EditText and Button in the following way

```
<LinearLayout
orientation="horizontal"
layoutwidth="match_parent"
layoutheight="wrap_content">

<EditText
layoutwidth="0dp"
layoutheight="wrap"
layout_weight=".8"/>

<Button
layoutwidth="0dp"
layoutheight="wrap"
layout_weight=".2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Make sure to change the weights according to your needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Linear layout to show both side by side and use 'match_parent' and 'wrap_content' appropriately.

Here's a piece of xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go!!" />

</LinearLayout>
```